# Why does the javascript arguments object behave so strangely when you try to modify it?

Tags: javascript, arguments

consider the following:

foo intends to take the arguments object and rearrange the order, moving arg1 to the position of arg2

```
function foo (args) {
    args[2] = args[1];
    args[1] = undefined;
}
```

`bar` calls foo with it's arguments

```
function bar (a, b, c) {
    foo(arguments);
    console.log(arguments);
}
```

I expect the result of the following to be something like `{ 0: 'hello', 1: undefined, 2: 'world' }`

```
bar('hello', 'world');
```

However, i get:

```
{
    0: 'hello',
    1: undefined,
    2: 'world',
    3: undefined,
    4: undefined,
    5: undefined,
    6: undefined,
    7: undefined,
    8: undefined,
    9: undefined,
    10: undefined,
    11: undefined,
    12: undefined,
    13: undefined,
    14: undefined,
    15: undefined,
    16: undefined,
    17: undefined,
    18: undefined,
    19: undefined
}
```

I am at a complete loss as to why this happens.
Anyone have any ideas?

I'm running this in a node.js environment

Comment: Well that's odd. It's probably related to you modifying something (`arguments`) that's not meant to be modified.

Comment: It seems like this is an issue with V8 because with browser testing the "problem" only manifests in Chrome, but doesn't using Moz Spidermonkey. TBH, I'd consider direct manipulation of the arguments "array" to be dangerous, and you'd be better off taking a copy with `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` before you start messing with it.

Comment: `arguments.length` is still only `2` though.

Comment: [This V8 issue](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=222#c12) might be related?

Comment: To be clear, `arguments` **isn't** an array. It's array-like. Applying array expectations might lead to unexpected results.

Comment: i tried to change the `.length` property but it doesnt make any difference

Comment: @spender That's usually what i do but unfortunately my particualr use-case requires that i modify the actual arguments object

Comment: That's an odd one... BTW, if you pass in 3 arguments, it doesn't resize arguments like that: `bar('hello', 'world', 'three')` returned `{ 0: 'hello', 1: undefined, 2: 'world' }` for me.

Comment: @StickyCube I find myself wondering what your use-case might be...

Comment: @joseph Interesting, maybe it's to do with setting arguments over the initial length of the array. Needto investigae more

Comment: @spender It's just a little utility for moving the final given argument of a function to the position of the last declared one if it's a function I was just seeing if you could actually do stuff like that and i stumbled across this peculiarity

Comment: It also works with 1 argument, resulting in 1 element shorter an array - for some reason 18 seems to be a magic number here.

Comment: If you add `'use strict';` to function `bar` it works as expected.

Comment: Since `arguments.length` is correct, any iteration based on this would still give the desired result. In a sense, aren't all indexes out of the dimensions _undefined_? Sure, showing those in the console is a bit confusing, but it's hardly a show stopper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`arguments object`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6) is not an array. It is a list with the internal type `Arguments`, with a `length` property and getters/setters for properties `0` to `len - 1` where `len` is the lesser of the number of declared arguments of the function and the number of elements you called the function. Once this object is created, the system will not increase/decrease `length` when you operate on its properties, and attempting to set it a `length` does not add/remove keys. The getters/setters for properties `0` to `len - 1` are indeed aliases to your argument names within the function (i.e., when you set `b = 1` you will see `arguments[1] === 1`).

What's happened when `foo` tries to set `args[2]` is addition of an integral property triggers V8 to resize the underlying array storage to 20 elements (it somehow should know that this is an `Arguments` type so it can probably set it to a hash property instead). If you set `args[20] = 1` it will be resized to 47, `args[100] = 1` will resize to 167, but setting `args[1026] = 1` will make it a sparse array (but first setting `args[1025] = 1` and then `args[2048]` does not make it sparse), etc.

After resized, `Object.keys` reports all `0` to `19` as properties, so [`console.log`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/console.js) (which calls [`util.format`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/util.js)) just prints all of them.

```
(function (a, b, c) { (function (args) { args[2] = 1; })(arguments); console.log(Object.keys(arguments)); })("hello", "world")

["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19"]
```

This is definitely a V8 bug, although it is very edgy.